# User external object fields in formula field

Tags: remote-objects

I have an external object called MyExternalObject__x but when I goto create a formula field on another object or even a custom button I cannot merge in fields from the external object.... IE: if I add {!MyExternalObject__x.Name}... When I try to save I get an error saving the MyExternalObject__x does not exist.

Is it possible to use external object fields in formula field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this in my Lightning org and you are correct, you cannot refer external object fields in formula field.
The following link gives you detailed limitations of external objects. However, I am not 100% sure but you can write a trigger on the External object, see if that solves your problem?

[External Data Integration Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_external_data.htm&language=en_US)

Do mark this as answered if it solves your problem. 
Cheers,
Siddhesh Kabe,
BE Awesome

Comment: You are welcome. But that was an interesting use-case, I am going to update my blogpost with the details.